# Is it ok to use slices as shared memory?

Tags: go, concurrency, shared-memory

Is it ok to use slices in a construction like this:

```
type buffer struct {
    values []int
    mutex sync.RWMutex
}
```

I ask because when we append to slice, there is a chance that we will copy the slice to the new place in memory.

Comment: "when we append to slice, there is a chance that we will copy the slice to the new place in memory" is a true fact but why do you think this would not be "ok"?

Comment: Appending to a slice that is accessed or modified concurrently from other goroutines isn't safe. However, if no appending takes place and each goroutine has exclusive access (read _and_ write) to a given slot of the slice, then you're safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most Go programming, people will assign slice back without performance concern in case `append` returns new memory since slices are reference value.

`b.values = append(b.values, i)`

```golang
type buffer struct {
    values []int
    mutex sync.RWMutex
}

func (b *buffer) Append(i int) {
    b.mutex.Lock()
    b.values = append(b.values, i)
    b.mutex.Unlock()
}
```